# Use Natural Language Processing to to Split Bad & Good Comments from an Employee Survey

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

So bit of a long shot here, and I apologize for the lack of information. However, I'm struggling to even know where to look now.

So I'm trying to split good and bad comments from a made-up survey of employees at a random company. All I have is a dataframe consisting of the comment an employee has made along with their managers ID code. The idea is to try and see how many good and/or bad comments are associated with a manager via their ID.

```
import pandas as pd 
trial_text=pd.read_csv("trial.csv")
trial_text.head()

   ManagerCode              Comment
0        AB123  Great place to work
1        AB123  Need more training
2        AB123  Hate working here
3        AB124  Always late home
4        AB124  Manager never listens
```

I've used NLTK quite a lot for data sets that include a lot more information so anything NLTK based won't be a problem. Like I say, with what I have, "Google" has far too much information that I don't know where to begin (or that is useful)! If there's anyone that might just have a suggestion that could put me on track that would be great!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need sentiment analysis. I don't think you will get amazing results with an off-the-shelf model though, because your responses are quite short and quite domain specific. In case you want to try anyway, here is an example of how to use the `vader` model with `nltk`:

```
from nltk.sentiment.vader import SentimentIntensityAnalyzer
sid = SentimentIntensityAnalyzer()
sid.polarity_scores('Great place to work')
>>> {'neg': 0.0, 'neu': 0.423, 'pos': 0.577, 'compound': 0.6249}
sid.polarity_scores('Manager never listens')
>>> {'neg': 0.0, 'neu': 1.0, 'pos': 0.0, 'compound': 0.0}
```

As you can see, your mileage may vary.

If you have lots of responses (thousands), a more viable strategy would be to manually label a sample of e.g. a few tens to a few hundred and to train your own sentiment classifier. Here are some good tutorials of how to do this with either [nltk](https://www.nltk.org/book/ch06.html) or [sklearn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/text_analytics/working_with_text_data.html)

Comment: yeah I used this earlier today. Didn't get the best results, but it worked well-enough, so cheers

Answer (score 2):

How about textblob? An example :

```
from textblob import TextBlob
TextBlob('this sounds pretty good!').sentiment
```

Output:

```
Sentiment(polarity=0.5625, subjectivity=0.8)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have smaller dataset, you can do sentiment analysis using logistic Regression as it is classification problem. You can find similar example here: [Sentiment Analysis using Logistic Regression](https://github.com/llSourcell/logistic_regression/blob/master/Sentiment%20analysis%20with%20Logistic%20Regression.ipynb)